Terraform plan on local shows No Changes after import but shows creation on github actions
I have a few resources deployed on Azure, when I import them (CDN profile & endpoints) locally to generate the state file, it shows No Changes, your infrastructure matches.
I have a git Generate plans workflow, which only shows changes, not apply, it shows the creation of those resources even though I have placed the locally generated terraform state file in the folder from where it picks the changes.
The terraform script is straightforward -
     data "azurerm_resource_group" "prresourcegroup" {
        name                                      = local.rgname
     }


    data "azurerm_storage_account" "frontendappstorage" {
        name                                      = "fastorage"
        resource_group_name                       = local.rgname
     }


    resource "azurerm_cdn_profile" "cdn-profile" {
      name                                              = "prcdnprofile"
      resource_group_name                               = data.azurerm_resource_group.prresourcegroup.name
      sku                                               = "Premium_Verizon"
      location                                          = "global"
      lifecycle {
        prevent_destroy = true
        ignore_changes = [
          tags
        ]
      }
    }

     resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "frontend-endpoint" {
       name                                              = "eptpr"
       profile_name                                      = azurerm_cdn_profile.cdn-profile.name
       resource_group_name                               = data.azurerm_resource_group.prresourcegroup.name
       location                                          = "global"
       optimization_type                                 = "GeneralWebDelivery"
       querystring_caching_behaviour                     = "IgnoreQueryString" : "NotSet"
       origin {
         name      = data.azurerm_storage_account.frontendappstorage.primary_web_host
         host_name = data.azurerm_storage_account.frontendappstorage.primary_web_host
       }

       origin_host_header = data.azurerm_storage_account.frontendappstorage.primary_web_host

       lifecycle {
         ignore_changes = [
           tags,
           origin,
           optimization_type,
           is_compression_enabled,
           global_delivery_rule
         ]
       }
     }

Github actions.yaml -
     name: Plan terraform changes
     description: Produces a plan of the changes to be made by Terraform
     
     runs:
       using: composite

       steps:
         - uses: cschleiden/replace-tokens@v1 # Replace tokens in TF files with environment variable values
           with:
             files: '["**/*.tf*","**/*.yaml*"]'

         - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v3

         - name: Terraform Init Frontend
               shell: bash
               working-directory: terraform/frontend
               run: terraform init

             - name: Terraform Validate Frontend
               shell: bash
               working-directory: terraform/frontend
               run: terraform validate

             - name: Terraform Plan Frontend
               shell: bash
               working-directory: terraform/frontend
               run: terraform plan --var-file=variables.tfvars -input=false -no-color >> ../../${{env.Environment-Name}}_plan.txt

             - name: Save plan
                   uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
                   with:
                     name: ${{env.Environment-Name}}_plan.txt
                     path: ${{env.Environment-Name}}_plan.txt  

This is only to Plan changes not actual apply.

Ensure that the locally generated Terraform state file is placed in the exact working directory (terraform/frontend) that the GitHub Actions workflow is using. The state file should match the working directory of your Terraform configuration.

It matches, I have checked it multiple times. deleted and tried again. State files are in Azure shared folder, while terraform/frontend is the working directory for the scripts.

So you are using a remote storage for the state file?

Yes, Azure container, whose url is mentioned via github pipeline - plan_dev:
name: Plan terraform changes to development
environment: development
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
env:
Environment-Name: dev
Storage-Access-Key: ${{secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY}}

In your terraform/frontend directory, make sure you have the correct backend configuration to pull the remote state from your Azure storage account.
and check pipeline is fetching the latest state file from the remote backend when performing terraform init. You could manually check if the state file in Azure matches the resources by running a terraform state pull to inspect the current state

Github was referencing the wrong state file which was causing the difference on local & git workflow.
